# How Do I Access Thread Local Storage From ml64.exe (MSVC 64-bit X64 Assembler)?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, thread-local, thread-local-storage

The following C function attempts to prevent recursion in multicore code in a thread-safe manner using a thread local storage variable.  However, for reasons that are somewhat complicated, I **NEED** to write this function in X64 assembler (Intel X86 / AMD 64-bit) and assemble it with ml64.exe from VC2010.  I know how to do this if I'm using global variables but I'm not sure how to do it properly with a TLS variable that has __declspec(thread).

```
__declspec(thread) int tls_VAR = 0;
void norecurse(  )
{
    if(0==tls_VAR)
    {
        tls_VAR=1;
        DoWork();
        tls_VAR=0;
    }
}
```

Note: This is what VC2010 kicks out for the function.  However, MASM (ml64.exe) doesn't support the `gs:88` or `OFFSET FLAT:` parts of the code.

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 

include listing.inc

INCLUDELIB MSVCRTD
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  norecurse
EXTRN   DoWork:PROC
EXTRN   tls_VAR:DWORD
EXTRN   _tls_index:DWORD
pdata   SEGMENT
$pdata$norecurse DD imagerel $LN4
    DD  imagerel $LN4+70
    DD  imagerel $unwind$norecurse
pdata   ENDS
xdata   SEGMENT
$unwind$norecurse DD 040a01H
    DD  06340aH
    DD  07006320aH
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
xdata   ENDS
_TEXT   SEGMENT
norecurse PROC
; File p:\hackytests\64bittest2010\64bittest\64bittest.cpp
; Line 19
$LN4:
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rbx
    push    rdi
    sub rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
; Line 20
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _tls_index
    mov rax, QWORD PTR gs:88
    mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:tls_VAR
    mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rax+rcx*8]
    cmp DWORD PTR [rbx+rdi], 0
    jne SHORT $LN1@norecurse
; Line 22
    mov DWORD PTR [rbx+rdi], 1
; Line 23
    call    DoWork
; Line 24
    mov DWORD PTR [rbx+rdi], 0
$LN1@norecurse:
; Line 26
    mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
    add rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
    pop rdi
    ret 0
norecurse ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Comment: Did you look at the code generated by VC for the tls variable access and reproduce that in your assembly?

Comment: You should tag this MSVC or windows or something. The answers for everything else will be a lot different.

Comment: @Mat: Yes, I did.  I can't figure out how to use a constant offset from gs in ml64.exe but I can move the constant to a register and access it that way.  A couple extra steps but it will probably work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your answer indicates the problem comes down finding the MASM equivalents to the following two lines in assembly listing generated by the Microsoft's C++ compiler:

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR gs:88
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:tls_VAR
```

The first line is easy. Just replace `gs:88` with `gs:[88]`.

The second line is less obvious. The `OFFSET FLAT:` operator is a red herring. It means use the offset relative to the beginning of the "FLAT" segment. With the 32-bit version of MASM, the FLAT segment is the segment that includes the entire 4G address space. This is the segment that's used for both the code and data segment as part of the 32-bit flat memory model. The 64-bit version of MASM doesn't support memory models, it essentially always assumes a 64-bit version of the flat memory model, so it doesn't support the FLAT keyword. As result the plain `OFFSET` operator ends meaning the same thing. (In fact with the 32-bit assembler, plain `OFFSET` also normally means the same thing because PECOFF only supports the flat memory model.)

However using `OFFSET` here won't work. That's because it would use the offset of the address of `tls_VAR` in memory relative to address 0. Or in other words, it would use the absolute address of `tls_VAR` in memory. What's needed here is the offset relative to the beginning of the TLS data section.

So the compiler must be doing something special here.  In order find out, I dumped the relocations in the object file generated while compiling your example C code:

```
> dumpbin /relocations t215a.obj
...  
RELOCATIONS #4
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000008  REL32                      00000000        14  _tls_index
 00000016  SECREL                     00000000         8  tls_VAR
 0000002D  REL32                      00000000         C  DoWork
...
```

As you can see it generates a relocation of type `SECREL` for the reference to `tls_VAR`.  This makes the relocation relative to the base of the section in the generated executable that that symbol appears in. In this case that's the `.tls` section, so this relocation generates an offset relative to the beginning of the section used for static TLS data.

So now the question becomes how to get MASM to generate the same SECREL relocation the compiler emits.  This turns out to have a easy solution as well, just replace `OFFSET FLAT:` with `SECTIONREL`.

So with these changes (and a bit of optimization) your function becomes:

```
    EXTERN  tls_VAR:DWORD
    EXTERN  _tls_index:DWORD
    EXTERN  DoWork:PROC

    PUBLIC  norecurse
_TEXT SEGMENT
norecurse PROC
    push rbx
    sub rsp, 32
    mov rax, gs:[88]
    mov ecx, _tls_index
    mov rbx, [rax + rcx * 8]
    cmp DWORD PTR [rbx + SECTIONREL tls_VAR], 0
    jne return
    mov DWORD PTR [rbx + SECTIONREL tls_VAR], 1
    call DoWork
    mov DWORD PTR [rbx + SECTIONREL tls_VAR], 0
return:
    add rsp, 32
    pop rbx
    ret
norecurse ENDP
_TEXT ENDS
    END
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm going to try this out today.

Comment: I ran into an issue with this.  I couldn't do `mov QWORD PTR [rbx + SECTIONREL tls_VAR],r12` and instead had to do these three instructions: `mov eax,SECTIONREL tls_VAR; add rax,rbx; mov QWORD PTR [rax],r12`

Comment: I think it's because `SECTIONREL tls_VAR` is a DWORD ??  Anyhow, the single instruction version gives "error A2024: invalid operand size for instruction"

Comment: Oh, and it looks like it works fine with a constant (i.e. 1) but not with a register as the source operand.

Comment: @Adisak Looks like a bug in MASM. SECTIONREL isn't working correctly with register offsets if the size of the operand isn't 32-bits. You can simply your workaround into two instructions: `mov eax, SECTIONREL tls_VAR; mov [rbx + rax], r12`.

Comment: Ah thank you... the two instructions is still more efficient than three :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work a hack around the issue.  My implementation in assember is less efficient than the C compiler generated code though because I was not able to figure out how to use the following two addressing modes:

1. mov rax, QWORD PTR gs:88
2. mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:tls_VAR

For (1), I had to load 88 into rax and use gs:[rax] to access the TLS-base for the thread.

For (2), the lack of `OFFSET FLAT` in MASM (ml64.exe) meant that I had to be more clever.  I computed the offset by subtracting `_tls_start` from the TLS-base for the thread that could be applied to TLS-variables in assembler to access their thread local values.

```
PUBLIC  norecurse
EXTRN   _tls_index:DWORD
EXTRN   _tls_start:DWORD
EXTRN   tls_VAR:DWORD
EXTRN   DoWork:PROC

_TEXT   SEGMENT

norecurse           PROC
    ; non-volatile
    push            rbx
    sub             rsp,32

    ; The gs segment register refers to the base address of the TEB on x64.
    ; 88 (0×58) is the offset in the TEB for the ThreadLocalStoragePointer member on x64
    mov             rax,88
    mov             edx, DWORD PTR _tls_index
    mov             rax, gs:[rax]
    mov             r11, QWORD PTR [rax+rdx*8]
    lea             r10, _tls_start
    ; r11 will be the the offset-adjusted TLS-Base
    sub             r11, r10

    ; ebx will be the the thread local address of tls_VAR
    lea             rdx, tls_VAR
    lea             rbx,[r11+rdx]

    cmp             DWORD PTR [rbx], 0
    jne             @F

    mov             DWORD PTR [rbx], 1

    call            DoWork

    mov             DWORD PTR [rbx], 0
@@:

    add             rsp,32
    pop             rbx

    ret
norecurse       ENDP

_TEXT   ENDS

    END
```

I'd love to see more efficient method or pointers on how to actually use the two addressing modes I couldn't figure out with MASM (ml64.exe) though.

Comment: While I answered my own question with a working solution, this is not the ideal answer I was looking for.  If anyone can solve the two issues mentioned above (or at least #2), I will accept that answer.

Comment: This really helped me, especially emulating `OFFSET FLAT` part. It's a pity you can't vote for an answer multiple times.

Comment: @arrowd Glad it helped -- it took me a while to figure this out.  It's not exactly the most straight-forwared solution.  If you can figure out how to use OFFSET FLAT with TLS please post an answer here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TlsGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686812%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), TlsSetvalue, and friends.

Comment: That doesn't work for __declspec(thread) at all.  It's a completely different dynamic TLS mechanism that requires TlsAlloc and will not work for statically initialized __declspec(thread) TLS variables.

Comment: I meant use TlsAlloc/TlsGet/Set instead of using __declspec(thread). Are you trying to access a __declspec declared variable from elsewhere?

Comment: I need to use __declspec(thread) because I need static initialization of the value.

Comment: The variable is declared __declspec(thread) in C code and I need to access it from an assembler routine.